# Disruptive java processes on local machine after connecting to yarn-managed spark cluster with sparklyr

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparklyr

I am using sparklyr to connect to a yarn-managed spark cluster that is not located on my server. I have a local installation of spark that acts as a client for the back-and-forth to the yarn cluster.

PROBLEM: I'm seeing some java processes that hang around on my local server (especially when I kill spark applications) and I have to manually kill them from the command line or else they disrupt future spark context creation. If I don't kill them for a while I eventually run out of memory on the local server.

QUESTION: Why are these java processes hanging around? What am I doing wrong? How can I set configs to avoid them?

I am creating my spark context using:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el7_4.x86_64/jre')
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/var/lib/Spark')
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR = '/usr/local/hadoop-2.8.3/etc/hadoop')
conf <- spark_config()
# conf$spark.executor.memory <- "3000M"
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 4
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 8
conf$spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname <- master
conf$spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address <- master:8032
conf$spark.yarn.access.namenodes <- paste0("hdfs://", master, ":8020,hdfs://", master, ":8020")
conf$spark.yarn.stagingDir <- paste0("hdfs://", master, ":8020/user/dzafar")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = conf)
```

One of the common error messages I'll get when this happens is:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminat
```

Thanks for the help on this, I'm pretty new to YARN but excited to get it up and running.

Comment: How are you killing the spark applications?

Comment: I've been using the yarn ui. The `Kill Application` button on the application's page.